# Get ES documents based on field that contains all input strings

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get all documents in ES that their nested field contains all the input strings i provide. E.g. i want to get all docs that their bets.betName have all the words -> over, score and goals.

I am using ES 7.12, my betName field is text, indexed and i am using the default analyzer.
What i have tried so far and doesn't work is

```html
GET /market2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "bets.betName": {
        "query": "over score goals",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
GET market2/_search
{
  "size": 1, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "bets.betName": {
              "query": "over score goals",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

All these queries they return a doc that contains over and score but not goals. It's like the AND operator is not working.
Any ideas how this can be achieved?

SOLUTION:

```html
GET market2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {"bets.betName": "over"}},
        {"match": {"bets.betName": "score"}},
        {"match": {"bets.betName": "goals"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your sample data set as well and from that data which you want in result and which you dont. That will help to understand question better and easy to answer.

Comment: if bets is of type "nested" then you need to use nested query. Normal queries will not work with nested fields